# Tracking data usage for network requests using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsurlsession

I am trying to figure out a way to find how much data is sent/received by my requests with AFNetworking. What are some of the best practices to solve this problem?

Example:

- do a GET to an endpoint `fakeapi/downloadlist`
- I want to know how many bytes were sent to the server and how many bytes were received back.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the `GET:parameters:success:failure:` [method](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/3.1.0/Classes/AFHTTPSessionManager.html#//api/name/GET:parameters:success:failure:) on the `AFHTTPSessionManager` for performing a GET request. The declaration for the method is:

```
- (nullable NSURLSessionDataTask *)GET:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(nullable id)parameters 
  success:(nullable void (^) (NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id _Nullable responseObject))success 
  failure:(nullable void (^) (NSURLSessionDataTask *_Nullable task, NSError *error))failure;
```

There are two blocks of interest here: One for success (named very smartly `success`) and another for a `failure` in the request.

Both of the blocks return a parameter of type NSURLSessionDataTask (which is nullable on the failure event, if that's the case then there was no response, most likely to happen when there's no internet connection). According to the [Apple Documentation for `NSURLSessionDataTask`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessiondatatask#relationships), which inherits from [`NSURLSessionTask`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessiontask?language=objc), it is possible to get the response object some other properties (take a look on the symbols section on the documentation):

```
int bytesReceived = ((int)[task countOfBytesReceived]);
int bytesSent     = ((int)[task countOfBytesSent]);
// Do something with the numbers from here...
```

Further from here, take a look on the [Symbols for NSURLSessionTask](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessiontask?language=objc#symbols) and take any other thing you need.